# HTML5 input pattern attribute - regex fails

Tags: html

I'm a bit stumped trying to get the following regex to work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="/....php">
  Amount: <input type="text" name="amount" pattern="^\$(\d{1,3}(\,\d{3})*|(\d+))(^\.\d{2})?$" title="Please enter as $XXX,XXX no decimal">
  <input type="submit">
</form>



</body>
</html>
```

I tried dropping the leading carrot and trailing dollar too, as I know these are implied, but it still won't validate the the number entered is of the form $XXX,XXX with no decimal. Other regex parsers are working fine and validate the regex should work: https://regex101.com/r/BZKMK4/1
Are there published limitations to the input regex you can use in the pattern attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simplified regex seems to do the trick: `\$\d{1,3}(,\d{1,3})*`

No need to specifically negate decimals with the `(^\.\d{2})?` - just not including anything here will make the field invalid if a decimal is typed since no dots are allowed in the first place. I think this is what was messing with it since JS regexes do not support this feature, and your link specified a PHP style regex, not JS

```css
input:invalid { 
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<label for="input-amount">Amount</label>
<input type="text"
       id="input-amount"
       pattern="\$\d{1,3}(,\d{1,3})*"
       placeholder="$XXX,XXX">
```

Also, a small suggestion from the UI-side of things, there's no need to make people type the `$` sign, just put that outside of the input next to it so that it's implied and all people have to worry about are the numbers.

Right now you type `$` alone and it's an invalid field, which is not a great experience.  here's my suggested change:

```css
.prefix,
input {
  border: 2px solid #CCC;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 1px;
}

.prefix {
  display: inline-block;
  border-right-width: 0;
}

input {
  border-left-width: 0;
}

input:invalid { 
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<label for="input-amount">Amount</label>
<span class="prefix">$</span><input type="text"
       id="input-amount"
       pattern="\d{1,3}(,\d{1,3})*"
       placeholder="XXX,XXX">
```

It's not perfect, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. That got me where I need to be. Here's my final regex:

```
   ^\$[1-9]\d{0,2}((,\d{3})*|\d*)$
```

Support with or without comma, ie $10,000 is valid, and so is $10000